# localStorage taking time to store token in react

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I'm trying to store a JWT Token into localStorage. It's storing properly without issues. But when I'm ending that token from localStorage as Authorization header in the API, it's getting null. But when I reload the page, I'm getting proper response from the database.
Here's the code:

**Home.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
setToken(queryParams.get("token"))
localStorage.setItem('token', token)

setRedirect(true)
}, []);

if (redirect) {
    return (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/chatroom",
          state: { token.id },
        }}
      />
    );
  }
return "";
```

**Apihelper.js**

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

const headers = {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
};

export const initiateChat = async (data) =>
  await axios.post(`${API}/room/initiate`, data, {
    headers,
 });
```

**Chatroom.js**

```
import { initiateChat } from "../Apihelper";

const Chatroom = (props) => {

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    initiateChat(user, props.location.state).then(({data}) => setUsers(data))
}, []);

}
```

When I'm hitting this `initiateChat` API, I'm getting 401 i.e. Invalid Token. But when I reload the page, I get the response as expected.
What I think is the first time it hits the API, it finds that there is not token in the localStorage since it might have been called before there was any data in localStorage. But when I reload it, I get proper response since now there is a token in localStorage.

How can I wait till it doesn't store token in localStorage ??

Comment: In `Home.js`, the first 3 lines inside `useEffect`: according to you, what are they supposed to do? And when are they executed? Before, or after `initiateChat`? Think ...

Comment: ```Home.js``` is the entry page. I'm trying to get the jwt token from the url and save it in localStorage to make the API calls with authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `token` as a dependency of your `useEffect` call:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
   setToken(queryParams.get("token"))
   localStorage.setItem('token', token)

   setRedirect(true)
}, [token]);
```